# SqlCommand and ExecuteReader return Non-Public Members

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I execute a scripted query from a .sql file with SqlCommand.

I get the result with an ExecuteReader.

But values are as non-public member and I can't access it.

Any idea why and how resolve that?

## Code

```
string root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string script = File.ReadAllText(root + @"..\SGBD\select_user_from_all_bases.sql");
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI";
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

conn.Open();

var users = new SqlCommand(script, conn).ExecuteReader();

foreach (var user in users)
{

}

conn.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you even looked at how you're supposed to use this API?

Comment: If you don't want all the fuss of dealing with that API, consider something like "dapper" (search on NuGet). The entire work is then: `var users = conn.Query<User>(script).ToList();`

Comment: @MarcGravell - Actually I want to expose this users in json so Dapper is perhaps what I search. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I find a solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8965906/652669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because ExecuteReader() returns a SqlDataReader, not the entries.

[Look at the documentation of the SqlDataReader to see how you should do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: note: `command` and `reader` should also have `using` statements.

Comment: Ok I tried that but reader[0] returned 0 so I thought it did't work. In fact this is the good result, I'm an idiot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you probably shouldn't be using `foreach`. For compatibility reasons, it needs to be implemented, but a `while (reader.Read())` loop is simpler here. That said, you can use `foreach` anyway if you want. The `user` values implement `IDataRecord`, and you can use that interface to access the values.

```
foreach (IDataRecord user in reader)
{
    // access user[0], user["field"], etc. here
}
```