# What's the best way to jSON serialize a .NET DataTable in WCF?

Tags: .net, json, wcf, serialization, json.net

When I configure WCF to use jSON serialization, and include a DataTable in one of my DataContracts, it serializes the DataTable to XML before serializing the entire DataContract to jSON. I want the DataTable to be serialized as jSON, not XML.

My questions are:

1. Why does it serialize the DataTable to XML first?
2. How can I get it to serialize to jSON instead?

Comment: Welcome to S.O. What have you tried in order to serialize to json?

Comment: Consider this and convert your datatable to JSON
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. DataTable is a pure .NET construct which cannot be (easily) represented in a lossless manner by JSON. DataTables contain lots of additional information which JSON cannot store: Primary keys, autoincs, allow nulls, caption, data type, indexes, etc. Serialization to XML/Binary are the only ways a DataTable can be serialized natively by .NET. This XML serialized DataTable is then serialized to JSON.
2. Use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) or [FastJSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON) to convert a DataTable to a plain, clean JSON-compatible version of the DataTable, which can be consumed by any JSON client, not just .NET WCF clients. You will lose all DataTable custom properties mentioned in (1) above and only get the field name/value JSON pair. Storage in this fashion is inefficient due to the duplication of field names in every row.

Don't use DataTable in your DataContract. If you want the benefits of a DataTable and  your clients are always going to be .NET, serialize the DataTable to a byte array via Binary Serialization and then optionally compress the resultant serialized byte stream. Expose a byte array in your DataContract. This will give you an efficient, fully lossless version of the DataTable on the client-side (after decompression and binary deserialization), not a watered-down JSON version of a DataTable (as offered by (2))...

Comment: Great answers. Thank you. My clients are not all .NET, and I quickly discovered the inefficiencies you mentioned. I am going to try modifying this approach so that I don't have to include the column/field names with every row.

Comment: i know this is an old thread, but fastjson supported datatable serialization/deserialization from version 1.7.7 which was released before june 2011. and the xml format is inefficent, it include cumbersome tag for each field AND row.

Comment: @Keith Blows, how about serializing a List of DataTables? How do you suggest to do that?

Comment: I created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/ec94e1a6048bd1bb4a2c737ad2d5f539) to test Newtonsoft.Json (meant to be ran in linqpad). The serialization works the way you'd hope.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
public string ConvertDataTabletoString(System.Data.DataTable dt)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue, my wcf service was not formatting the json properly while converting it from Dataset to Json.
I got it working by using the following solution:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
```

dsData is my Dataset

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsData);
return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(json, "application/json;charset=utf-8", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

and "Message" will be the return type.

Comment: This answer really saved my life today :)
I gave up on looking for simple method to return DataTable from db to JSON **without** declaring objects explicitly for every table/procedure.
My mistake was that my `OperationContract` was returning serialized json simply as `string`. That way, it required, for example, using `JSON.parse` client-side. Changing return type to `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` and using `WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(string)` as shown above **works perfectly**! :)

Comment: I've never actually thought that You can do stuff like this with WCF WS - setting response instead of just returning `int/string/class/List<T>  etc`

Answer (score 2):

According to the chart on its homepage, [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is really your only option - you can quickly get it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).  Fortunately it's a great library and very easy to use.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDataSet, new DataSetConverter());
```

Note that [Rich Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer) has a great post with more details, and he also includes some custom work he did to use `JavaScriptSerializer` with (rather extensive) custom converters for the sake of comparison.

Comment: This worked, but then I quickly realized that the data column/field names are being included with EVERY row, making it very inefficient, as mentioned by Keith. I am going to try modifying the DataTableConverter and DataRowConverter so that I don't repeat all of these column/field names.

Comment: @rhyno what was your end solution for not repeating all of the column/field names? I have an idea of what I was going to do, but if you have already accomplished that it would save me some time.