# Loading Data Table dynamically in C# into JS Array

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, datatable

I am trying to load my `dynamically generated Datatable` during runtime into `JS array` in javascript. But cannot pass it through webservice as only static methods can be called through javascript.How to return the datatable into javascript.

aspx.cs file :

```
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//on button click it reads file path of excel and stores it in a string path 
}

private DataTable ReadExcelWithStream(string path)

{
//method reads the excel file and stores it in a dt
ForJs(dt);
     return dt;
 }
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
 public static DataTable ForJs(DataTable dt)
 {

     return dt;
 }
```

aspx file :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function InsertLabelData() {
           PageMethods.ForJs(onSuccess, onFailure);

        }

             function onSuccess(dt) {

    //attach the table to dhtmlx grid
    }
```

**But the datatable is not passed to the javascript.
How to pass the datatable to javascript from c# ?
or any other methods to pass the datatable from c# to JS**

Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: A brief code sample might help, at the web service layer. Are you using WebAPI?

Comment: @Jake : I am trying it in webservices.

Answer (score 0):

> duplicate?/related question: [Dynamically pass datatable from C# to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854620/dynamically-pass-datatable-from-c-sharp-to-javascript)

You can not simply pass an(y) object to JavaScript. It has to be in a usable format. Like an array or serialized to XML or JSON. Also "[DataTables contain lots of additional information which JSON cannot store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17931096)".

Take a look at [how to pass c# datatable to a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567990/how-to-pass-c-sharp-datatable-to-a-javascript-function) or [What's the best way to jSON serialize a .NET DataTable in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928513/whats-the-best-way-to-json-serialize-a-net-datatable-in-wcf) for more information on this subject.