# ASP.Net : DataTable convert to JSON with Hierarchy

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, datatable

Hi I'm having a problem in converting my dataTable to JSON format but i cannot get the output that i want.

Here is the example of the datatable

```
 Parent        Child
   P1           c1
   P1           c2
   P1           c3
   P2           c4
```

the output that I need is:

```
 [{
    Parent:P1,
    Child:[
            {c1},
            {c2},
            {c3}
           ]
 },
 {
    Parent:P2
    Child:[{c4}]
 }]
```

But the Output that i always get is:

```
    [{Parent:P1, Child:c1}, {Parent:P1, Child:c2}, {Parent:P1, Child:c3}, {Parent:P2,
           Child:c4}]
```

Comment: I've used this one but still not get the output i want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code to get your desired result.

```
public class ParentNode
{
    public ParentNode()
    {
        this.Child = new List<ChildNode>();
    }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public List<ChildNode> Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildNode
{
    public string Child { get; set; }
}

class DataTableTOJSON
{   
    public static string GetJSON(DataTable dt)
    {            
        List<ParentNode> parent = new List<ParentNode>();            

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var innerRow = dt.Rows[i]["Parent"];
            var objParent = new ParentNode();
            bool alreadyExists = parent.Any(x => x.Parent.Contains(innerRow.ToString()));

            if (alreadyExists)
                continue;

            DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("[Parent]='" + innerRow + "'");

            for (int k = 0; k < foundRows.Count(); k++)
            {
                var objChild = new ChildNode();
                objChild.Child = foundRows[k]["Child"].ToString();
                objParent.Child.Add(objChild);
            }

            objParent.Parent = innerRow.ToString();
            parent.Add(objParent);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return jsonString.Serialize(parent);
    }
}
```

**Your will get the following output.**

[{"Parent":"P1","Child":[{"Child":"c1"},{"Child":"c2"},{"Child":"c3"}]},{"Parent":"P2","Child":[{"Child":"c4"}]}]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, I'm not able to use the "var" type variable because I'm using .net 2.0 for this project. also I cannot use the linq type code. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance...