# How to convert datatable to json object

Tags: c#, json

My datatable is in below format

**MCuserid Firsatname address1 address2   city      educationinfo institute degree**

1760        Rickert     vbn    addresstwo  hyderabad              Second College Second Degree

1766     Abhinav    jhgjkhk testaddress                                   mtech

1766     Abhinav    jhgjkhk testaddress                                   BTech

I need output in following json format in c#

```
[

{
    "MCUserID" : 1760,
    "FirstName": "Rickert",
    "Address1" : "vbn",
    "Address2" : "address two",
    "city      : "hyderabad"
    "EducationInfo": [
        {
           Institute: "Second College",
           Degree: "Second Degree",
         }
]
},
{    
  "MCUserID"   : 1766,
    "FirstName": "Abhinav",
    "Address1" : "jhgjkhk",
    "Address2" : " test address",
    "city      : ""
    "EducationInfo": [
        {
           Institute: "",
           Degree: "mtech",
         },
         {
           Institute: "",
           Degree: "btech",
         }
        ]
```

}
]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert datatable to json in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: In this multiple educational details i want like above. i did't found in that link.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp

Comment: @vidya did you atleast tried that link to check the output? If yes, then post the output result so that we can validate it.

Comment: Yes i tried with that code but am unable to get multiple educational details

Comment: @vidya I think your json string is wrong could you please check it again.

Comment: I have changed json result

Comment: You JSON is incorrect. Have you truncated that before pasting in question?

Comment: may  I know where it is incorrect.

Comment: @vidya In the middle of the "EducationInfo" array of the second person, there is another (invalid) "EducationInfo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that each row in the `DataTable` is a simple set of name/value pairs, but you want each person's `EducationInfo` as another layer in the result JSON. Furthermore you want multiple rows to become a single JSON object if all fields *but* `EducationInfo` match.

There isn't going to be a simple "Go()" method that will do this for you out of the box.

I suggest creating `Student` and `EducationInfo` classes to hold the information, and aggregate the data yourself into a `Student[]` array.

Then you simply serialize them using your favorite serializer. As a side effect, this makes debugging so much easier.