# Import/Export DataGridView with format C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, import, export

I've create a `DataGridView` in the interface builder from Visual Studio. The DataGridView has three columns of which one of them contains checkboxes.
As the application starts the datagridview should be empty (except for the headers). That's why the DataGridView doesn't have a `DataSource` at this moment. I'm trying to export this to a XML file so I can import this file the next time I open the application.

I've tried many ways to export and import my DataGridView but none of them worked fine. Is there a proper way to import and export datagridviews with keeping them format?

Saving the DataGridView to another format than XML is also fine, but as the application will have to run at multiple computers which will all create many files at a server, the filesize should be small.

Comment: json is small, have a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the grid to a datatable, and use `datatable.ReadXml("filename.xml")` and `datatable.WriteXml("filename.xml")`

Comment: thanks. I've tried this already but binding the grid to a datatable causes problems when using checkboxes in cells.

Comment: +1 from me, it worked just fine.  @Maarten1909 I've provided an example in my answer how it worked.  If that still doesn't help, what problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

As [rlee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4950362/rlee) pointed out, `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` should work.  The most basic raw example I put together worked just fine with checkboxes in cells.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private DataTable table;

  public Form1()
  {
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.table = new DataTable("Table");
    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Check", typeof(bool));
    DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Text", typeof(string));
    this.table.Columns.Add(col1);
    this.table.Columns.Add(col2);

    this.table.ReadXml("test.xml");
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.table;
  }

  private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    this.table.WriteXml("test.xml");
  }
}
```

Then save an xml file named `test.xml` where the `.exe` file is located:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Table>
    <Check>true</Check>
    <Text>Row 0</Text>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Check>false</Check>
    <Text>Row 1</Text>
  </Table>
</DocumentElement>
```