# Serialize data from database in JSON Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asmx

I am creating a web service in asp.net that serialize data in JSON Format, and access this webservice via JQuery

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
namespace Chart_WebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public DataTable GetData()
        {
           string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
           {
               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
               {
                   using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                   {
                       cmd.Connection = con;
                       sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                       using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                       {
                           dt.TableName = "Customers";
                           sda.Fill(dt);
                           return dt;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Please help me to complete this solution because I do not have idea to complete it
Hope at you guys!

Comment: The "Please do my work" questions usually are not very welcome, if you have any doubt, ask about it, don't ask others to do your job.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: What is a problem? Wrong response format? If yes, then how do you send request?

Comment: Agree with @Gusman here is the link that can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp

Comment: As an aside: SQL Server 2016 is getting `FOR JSON`... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

Comment: Consider this method to convert your `datatable` to `JSON`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Ali maybe, but step 1 of any question that starts "how do I do {x} with a DataTable" is always (or at least, *should* always be) "for the love of life itself, **stop using DataTable**"

Answer (score 3):

I would not return a `DataTable`. You can use raw ADO.NET and fill your result into a simple `Dictionary<string, object>`. With `Newtonsoft.Json` you can serialize the dictionary and return it.

Comment: Yup, that would work; personally I'd probably populate a `Customer` model (via dapper or similar) just to give the serializer the extra context (and the ability to deserialize), and the ability to control the names etc a bit more flexibly, but fundamentally this would work fine.

Comment: Yes, a model would be nice. But i choce a Dictionary, because he used `select * from ...` in his quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Well you better use Data Reader for this solution then convert to a List , this List will be serialized to JSON, the code will look like this :

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var comm = new SqlCommand(command, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                       Customers= reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x=>
                        new Customer
                        {
                            ID = (int)x["ID"],
                            name = x["name"].ToString(),

                        }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Customers);
```

And that's it