# Convert Datatable into Json Object in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

I'm Joinnes from Indonesia. I want to ask about converting my datatable into json object. I'm using asp.net with Vb. How can i convert my datatable into Json Like this:

```
    {
"awb": "81903054216",
"detail":
{
"shipped_date": "23-06-2016 08:24:00",
"delivered_date": "24-06-2016 10:54:00",
"services_code": "reguler",
"actual_amount": 33150,
"weight": 1000,
"final_status": 200,
"sender": {
"name": "ABCD",
"addr": "JL. ABCD",
"zipcode": 12345,
"city": "XXXX",
"geoloc": "xxx.bbb, xxx.aaa"
},
"receiver":{
"name": "BCDA",
"addr": "JL. BCDA",
"zipcode": 12345,
"city": "XXXX",
"geoloc": "xxx.bbb, xxx.aaa"
},
"driver":{
"id": "940184928",
"name": "driver A",
"phone": "12303523941",
"photo": ".com/potonya.jpg"
}
},
"history": [
{
"date_time": "20-JUN-2016 12:54:00",
"city_name": "XXXX",
"status": "manifested",
"status_code": 101,
"note": "something something",
"receiver": ""
},
{
"date_time": "21-JUN-2016 10:54:00",
"city_name": "XXXX",
"status": "Pickup Failed",
"status_code": 151,
"note": "something 1",
"receiver": ""
},
{
"date_time": "23-JUN-2016 12:54:00",
"city_name": "XXXX",
"status": "Shipping",
"status_code": 100,
"note": "something 2",
"receiver": ""
},
{
"date_time": "24-JUN-2016 10:54:00",
"city_name": "YYYY",
"status": "Delivered",
"status_code": 200,
"note": "something 3",
"receiver": "SETYAWAN"
}
]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your response :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert datatable to JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This code snippet from  [Convert Datatable to JSON String in C#, VB.NET](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/c-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-c.html)might help you.

Answer (score 1):

for VB

```
 Public Function ConvertDataTabletoString() As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=true")
       Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select title=City,lat=latitude,lng=longitude,description from LocationDetails", con)
       con.Open()
       Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       da.Fill(dt)
       Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
       Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
       Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
       For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
          row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
          For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
             row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
          Next
          rows.Add(row)
       Next
       Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
    End Using
 End Using
```

End Function

for C#

```
 public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=true"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title=City,lat=latitude,lng=longitude,description from LocationDetails", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP needs solution in VB.net :) Though it's correct way to convert datatable into JSON using C#.net. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your datatable into JSON format by doing this.

```
Public Function GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String

     Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(From dr As DataRow In dt.Rows Select dt.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().ToDictionary(Function(col) col.ColumnName, Function(col) dr(col)))

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple

First add nuget package Newtonsoft.json
Than include it in your project like

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
```

Than
Convert datatable to json like this

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```