# How to populate JavaScript array from database using asp.net and SQL server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have below table in my SQL Server database:

```
 ---------------------------
| Id | Title | DecimalDigit |
 ---------------------------
|1   | USD   | 2            |
 ---------------------------
|2   | EUR   | 2            |
 ---------------------------
|3   | JYN   | 4            |
 ---------------------------
|4   | TBH   | 0            |
 ---------------------------
```

and I want to have this data in client side in a javascript array. My final javascript array would be like this.

```
var cur=[{id:1 , title:"USD" , decimaldigit:2} , 
         {id:2 , title:"EUR" , decimaldigit:2} , 
         {id:3 , title:"JYN" , decimaldigit:4} , 
         {id:4 , title:"TBH" , decimaldigit:0} 
        ];
```

How can I retrieve my required data in asp.net and pass them to javascript array?

Comment: Yes, but whats your question here?

Comment: What you need is `JSON.parse()` to convert JSON string into JS object/array. Please add more information how you retrieve the data from SQL Server DB and relevant JS code, make sure it contains [mcve].

Comment: You should make a JSON of retrieved list from SQL.

Comment: there are alot of different ways to achieve this, 
You can use ADO.NET OR Entity Framework in ASP.NET to get data from SQL then Return Json from ASP.net Controller,
Then send ajax request from js and get your array

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto what more information is needed?

Comment: @Ans Bilal Can you please provide codes?

Comment: @Behnam for sure. But what way do you wanna choose?

Comment: @Ans Bilal the easiest one.

Comment: @Behnam do you know the basic of ASP.net ? I assume that you are using MVC so do you know the routing and other things ?

Comment: @Ans Bilal  NO :-(

Comment: Then bro a single code example cannot help you, you need to learn some basics of ASP.NET, and then AJAX , I cannot write the whole code in one example

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know what a connection string is?

Comment: @Spangle Yes I know

Comment: @Ans Bilal  I know asp.net and ajax but i dont know MVC

Comment: @Behnam, then take a look at https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-JSON-data-object-from-WebMethod-PageMethod-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this to building a string, which then can be parse in the client side to JSON:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Title] VARCHAR(4)
   ,[DecimalDigit] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Title], [DecimalDigit])
VALUES (1, 'USD', 2)
      ,(2, 'EUR', 2)
      ,(3, 'JYN', 4)
      ,(4, 'TBH', 0);

SELECT 
'[' +
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',{id:' + CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(12))  + ', title: "' + [Title]  + '", decimaldigit:' + CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(12))  +'}'
        FROM @DataSource
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1
  ,1
  ,''
)
+ ']';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in MVC and using Linq then you can return Json value as shown below.

```
 public ActionResult ConvertDataIntoArray()
 {
     var result = _db.jsonDatas.ToList();           
     return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Here `jsonDatas` is the name of table.
The returned output will look like as shown below.

```
[{"Id":1,"Title":"USD","DecimalDigit":2},{"Id":2,"Title":"EUR","DecimalDigit":2},{"Id":3,"Title":"JYN","DecimalDigit":4},{"Id":4,"Title":"TBH","DecimalDigit":0}]
```

You can further use it in view and manipulate as per your requirement.

Comment: You can also convert data table to json array. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp