# How to check values of a field from a datatable in JavaScript created by C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, powerbi, asp.net-4.5

I have a DataTable object in C#, I pass the object to my aspx class in JavaScript like below. In JavaScript, I have a loop over the pages of a PowerBI report. All I need to do is to compare if the PageLists (from c#) includes page.DisplayName and do some process based on that. See the code below:

**C#:**

```
DataTable PagesList = null; //(this is globally defined)
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PagesList = sql.QueryDataTable(String.Format("select PageLabel, DefaultPage from myTable where ReportID = '{0}';",ReportID));
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
   var pageslist = "<%=PagesList%>";
   alert(pageslist); //This pops up: "Table"

   report.getPages().then(function (pages) {  
        var allpages = ''
        pages.forEach(function(page) { 
            if(pageslist.includes(page.displayName) > -1) //this is not working properly
            {  
               allpages = allpages+'<button type="button" onclick=setPage(\''+page.name+'\')>'  + page.displayName+'</button>';
            }
        });
        ...
        ...
```

Here, it is not working as I expected, if part always returns false. What is the best way for this case to check if pageslist include page.displayName or not? How can I receive the items of the pageslist? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot loop the contents of a C# DataTable like that. You need to serialize it as json, xml etc and send it to the front-end where it can be read by javascript.

Comment: As @VDWWD said, you will probably want to serialize your DataTable to JSON.  See Newtonsoft: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17398019/1617161

Comment: Also, .includes() returns a boolean, so your condition of > -1 is always true.  See .includes() docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Tried IndexOf as well. Working on DataTable to Json now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `includes` which return `true` or `false` so you dont need this part :  `> -1`. You can change your condition :

```
 if(pageslist.includes(page.displayName))
```

or you can use `indexOf` :

```
 if(pageslist.indexOf(page.displayName) > -1)
```

Comment: Tried this already, didn't work. Main problem here that I cannot reach the values in the pageslist.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli What do you get when you console.log : pageslist and pages

Comment: It says only: Table. No sub element. @Emad Dehnavi

Comment: Don't use alert, console.log to see the whole object

Comment: I use console.log as well. Still says Table only. I was expecting to see Rows or Columns too.