# how to deserialize Json-Object in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am able to get the element to Code-Behind by Using the Ajax-Call But I am unable to Deserialize 
the element in Code-Behind in asp.net

This is my Ajax call

```
function responseData2() {

    var demodata = [];

    var oListbox = $("#submitlistbox2").each(function () {
        var data = $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
        alert("The Names are: " + data);

        demodata.push({
            var_name_data: data,
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        data: "{ 'selectedJobSheet': '" + demodata + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            alert(data);
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

My Code-Behind: How to retrive the element In Code behind:My ajax call returning data in Single string value "[object Object]"

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object Details4(string selectedJobSheet)
{    
    try
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select customer_id,first_name from jobsheetDetails", con))
            {
                string _data = "";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    _data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                }
                return _data;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

How to deserialize the element and how bind the element to list or array

Comment: Use a JSON library, such as [NewtonSoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and deserialise the JSON to a model. However you should note that you're only sending a single object, so you don't need a List or Array at all

Comment: In .NET Core 3.0 or higher there is [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) namespace to serialise and deserialise json (as an alternative to Newtonsoft.JSON) and it is enabled by default in the Web apps

Comment: if you add Rows like``JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0].Rows)``, gives you the same result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datatable to JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What is the point of that try/catch in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```
function responseData2() {
  var demodata = [];
  var oListbox = $("#submitlistbox2").each(function() {
    var data = $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
    alert("The Names are: " + data);
    demodata.push({
      var_name_data: data,
    });
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    data: { selectedJobSheet: demodata },
    success: function(results) {
      data = $.parseJSON(results.d);
      alert(data);
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function(response) {
      alert(response);
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
```

This will pass the Object to your post data. The way you had constructed it, you were passing a string and would not contain the data you expected. .NET can just read this as a Request like normal.

Since `demodata` is an Array of Objects, when you write:

```
"{ 'selectedJobSheet': '" + demodata + "'}"
```

This will create a String that is:

```
{ 'selectedJobSheet': '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'}
```

So it will not be passing the details you want. You can try it with `$.param()`:

```
data: $.param({ 'selectedJobSheet': demodata });
```