# .NET Core API - Convert DataTable to JSON (Deep)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, datatable, json.net

I am executing a stored procedure on my server which returns a DataTable.  The DataTable has some columns that have JSON data in them.  When I return the result to the client the top-level of the DataTable is properly formatted to JSON but the columns with JSON data are returned as strings.  How can I convert the entire table (including columns with JSON) to JSON before returning to the client?

DataTable

```
ColA        ColB         ColC
1           Test         [{"ColD":2,"ColE":"Another Test"}]
```

What I'm Getting

```
[
  {
    "ColA": 1,
    "ColB": "Test",
    "ColC": "[{\"ColD\":2,\"ColE\":\"Another Test\"}]"
  }
]
```

What I Need

```
[
  {
    "ColA": 1,
    "ColB": "Test",
    "ColC": [
      {
        "ColD": 2,
        "ColE": "Another Test"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp/17398078#17398078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a breakthrough after posting the question.  I created an extension method for the `DataTable` that would convert the `DataTable` to a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`.  In the process I check for values that start with `[` or `{` and deserialize them using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> ToJson(this DataTable dt)
{
    var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (row[col].ToString().StartsWith('{') || row[col].ToString().StartsWith('['))
            {
                dict[col.ColumnName] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(row[col].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                dict[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
            }
        }
        list.Add(dict);
    }

    return list;
}
```