# How to produce JSON strings from SQL Server queries via TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql

I wanted to know if there is any function or something to convert the SQL select query result to JSON string format?

For example, SQL select query result is,

```
current   target
-----------------
  500      1000
  1500     2000
```

**JSON result:**

```
[{"current":500,"target":1000},{"current":1500,"target":2000}]
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312982/from-datatable-in-c-sharp-net-to-json

Comment: have a look here https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41597)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([current] INT, [target] INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(500   ,   1000),
(1500  ,   2000)


SELECT '[' +  STUFF((SELECT ',{"current":' + CAST([current] AS VARCHAR(30)) 
   + ',"target":' + CAST([target] AS VARCHAR(30)) + '}'
FROM @TABLE
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') + ']'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41597/0)**:

```
[{"current":500,"target":1000},{"current":1500,"target":2000}]
```

Comment: I would update code to include the inner quotes:
``+ CAST([target] AS VARCHAR(30)) +``
to
``+ '"' + CAST([target] AS VARCHAR(30)) + '"'``

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify version.

In SQL Server 2016 you will be able to do something like

```
SELECT [current], 
       target
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY [current]
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

[More details here](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/sql-server-2016-json-support/) or in the [official pre release documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882(v=sql.130).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(( SELECT
                  [current],target 
                  FROM YourTable
                  FOR JSON PATH
               ))
```

Works well with minimal effort. I generally convert the output to a List<Dictionary<string,dynamic>> in C#/.Net (if I don't have an existing model).